# DateRange Picker with multiple ranges (comparison) for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, date-range, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I am looking to find a date range picker for Angular 2+ that works similar to this Vue component that I've found.  I have searched and searched, and I haven't been able to find anything.  If anyone knows of something, I would be forever grateful!  I feel like it must exist somewhere out there!

[Vue date range picker that I'd like to find something similar for Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IkNB.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately your question is likely to get closed because it's not a specific programming question. More: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the fisrt example of material date picker you has [an example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples). If you use another datepicker like the [datepicker of ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range) remember that you can give style to the days in function anothers values